# built-in zoom control not work if i have ontouch event in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient, pinchzoom

i am using webiview and i override onTouchEvent than built-in zoom control is not working.

```
    wv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
        {

            if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                x_down = (int) arg1.getX();
                y_down = (int) arg1.getY();

            Log.v("log", "x pos is "+x_down +"y pos is "+y_down);

            }

            else if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                x_up = (int) arg1.getX();
                y_up = (int) arg1.getY();

            Log.v("log", "x pos is "+x_up +"y pos is "+y_up);


            if((x_down-x_up)>30)
            {
                wv.loadData("<img src=\"myurl_1\">", "text/html", null);
            }
            else if((x_up-x_down)>30)
            {
                 wv.loadData("<img src=\"myurl_2\">", "text/html", null);
            }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning always true from the `onTouch` method, which means that you are the only one responsible for handling touch events..
you should return true only in the cases you want, and return `super.onTouch` in the other cases..

Answer (score 0):

```
       webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

add this code to your webview 
i hope it works